# Does the Yoneda embedding tell us the set of all maps from a compact genus zero surface to the sphere is isomorphic to SO(3)?

Tags: category-theory

I am just getting my head around the Yoneda embedding (and lemma) and want to check if my understanding is correct.

The surface classification theorem says that every closed orientable compact genus zero surface $X$ is homeomorphic to $S^2$. If we consider the Yoneda embedding of the category of closed surfaces where morphisms are homeomorphisms, then $S^2 \mapsto Hom(S^2,S^2)$ and $X \mapsto Hom(S^2,X)$. But $Hom(S^2,S^2) \cong SO(3)$ so does it mean that $Hom(S^2,X) \cong SO(3)$?

Comment: Which category are you considering? The set of continuous maps from S² to itself is much larger than SO(3) (it's not connected, and it contains noninvertible maps).

Comment: Thank you, yes I was considering the morphisms in the category of surfaces to be homeomorphisms. Edited.

Comment: This has nearly the same problem.  $SO(3)$ is the group of homeomorphisms induced by linear maps when you regard $S^2$ as the unit sphere in $R^3$.

Comment: And if you only consider homeomorphisms, then clearly $\mathrm{Hom}(S^2, X) = \varnothing$ if $X$ isn't homeomorphic to the sphere. I don't think that Yoneda's lemma tells you what you think it does. I think it would help if you stated explicitly the version of Yoneda's lemma you want to apply.

Comment: Well I am trying to understand just the Yoneda embedding, where objects in a category map to their hom-sets in $\mathbf{Set}$. I think the problem here is my construction of the category is too restrictive. With homeomorphisms, there are no morphisms between $S^2$ and $X$ in this 'category'. I guess I was trying to see if the Yoneda embedding would tell me if there was more structure to homeomorphisms between surfaces.

Comment: The basic problem is you are not stating the Yoneda lemma carefully.  This is common enough when people first meet the subject and can be overcome by a bit of care.  Your statements $S^2 \mapsto Hom(S^2,S^2)$ and $X \mapsto Hom(S^2,X)$ suggest you are using the contravariant Hom functor, so that its values are covariant set valued functors.  usually Yoneda embedding refers to the covariant Hom functor with contravariant set-valued functors as values.  Yu just need to write it all out much more carefully with a textbook (or web sie) in front of you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In any (locally small) category $\mathscr C$, if there is an isomorphism between $a$ and $b$, then the presheaves $\hom_{\mathscr C}(-,a)$ and $\hom_{\mathscr C}(-,b)$ are isomorphic. You don't need Yoneda's lemma for that : it just follows from the fact that $c \mapsto \hom_{\mathscr C}(-,c)$ is a functor.

So, working in the category of surfaces and continuous maps where $X$ and $S^2$ are isomorphic, you end up with a isomorphism between $\hom(-,S^2)$ and $\hom(-,X)$. Of course, it gives you a isomorphisms of sets (i.e. a bijection)
$$ \hom(S^2,S^2) \simeq \hom(S^2,X). $$
So it just says that $\hom(S^2,X)$ has the same cardinality as $\hom(S^2,S^2)$. If you have a group structure you like on $\hom(S^2,S^2)$, feel free to transport it to $\hom(S^2,X)$, but this isn't news (I mean you can put that structure on any other set of the right cardinality).